# How to filter the first and the last row based on a condition in the last row in R

Tags: dplyr

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
x <- seq(1,100, by = 1)
y <- 'A'
z <- 'A'
df1 <- data.frame(ID = x, Status = y, Next_Status = z)
x1 <- seq(1,50, by = 1)
y1 <- 'A'
z1 <- 'I'
df2 <- data.frame(ID = x1, Status = y1, Next_Status = z1)
df <- rbind(df1, df2)
df$Date <- seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-05-30'), by = 'day')
```

I want to filter the dataframe in such a way that I retain the first row and last row(arranged by Date) of an ID, which has Status = 'A' and Next_Status = 'I'(at a later date)

I tried filtering the data frame by this:

```
df_filtered <- df %>% filter(Status == 'A' & Next_Status == 'I')
```

The problem with this is I lose the information of the fisrt day for that ID when it was 'A'. I ultimately would like to find the number of days a particular ID remained in 'A' status. Therefore, I was thinking if I could filter the dataframe by first and last row based on the condition in the last row(Status == 'A' & Next_Status == 'I'), I could then compute the number of days it was in status 'A' before it changed to 'I'. I was wondering if there is any dplyr solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the general character of the data, but a simple way to bracket it would be to do something like

```
df %>% group_by(ID, Status) %>% summarise(begin=min(Date), end=min(Date))
```

This would give the first and last entries for each state. Alternatively, you could filter for `Status == 'A'` and summarise by min/max.

EDIT: In response to the comment below, I think you would want to do a tidyr `spread` to get the data into a digestible form. We combine `Status` and `Next_Status` into a single column, then get the time when we entered that state, then spread that across multiple columns.

```
df %>% mutate(State=paste(Status, Next_Status, sep='-')) %>%
  group_by(ID, State) %>% summarise(Start=min(Date)) %>%
  filter(State == 'A-A' | State == 'A-I') %>%
  spread(State, Start) %>% as.data.frame
```

Which gives something like:

```
     ID        A-A        A-I
1     1 2019-01-01 2019-04-11
2     2 2019-01-02 2019-04-12
3     3 2019-01-03 2019-04-13
...
48   48 2019-02-17 2019-05-28
49   49 2019-02-18 2019-05-29
50   50 2019-02-19 2019-05-30
51   51 2019-02-20       <NA>
52   52 2019-02-21       <NA>
53   53 2019-02-22       <NA>
54   54 2019-02-23       <NA>
55   55 2019-02-24       <NA>
56   56 2019-02-25       <NA>
57   57 2019-02-26       <NA>
58   58 2019-02-27       <NA>
```

Comment: So my case is that I want to get only the IDs which have started with 'A' and then went 'I' at some day. I might have some IDs which have been 'A' and continue to be 'A' till now and I don't want them. By running the above dplyr solution, I am including all those which are still 'A'. Further, the dates may not be continous, it depends on if a particular ID has got a hit. So my best approach is probably to see which IDs have changed from 'A' to 'I' and then find the number of days between when it has changed from 'A' to 'I'.

Comment: Please let me know if my updates above have clarified things.

Comment: It does! Works as expected